# Resizing controls in cell of TableLayout

Tags: c#, winforms

please let me first attach the picture, it is easier to describe on the picture:

[image]

TableLayout is set to Dock->Fill for the Table-layout which is inside that GroupBox.

If I change the Anchor of the Group-box to say Left,Top,Right....then When I resize the forms from its right side border, Only the controls on the second column of table-layout are resizing and not the controls in the left side of the table-layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must go to edit rows and columns of your table layout and choose the percent size type for the second column

Comment: I have put them all on "AutoSize"